# how to add delivery costs for particular day and time in magento

Tags: magento

I want to add delivery costs for particular day and time in Magento. Do we need to add code or can be done using payment rules or by some other functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this in Magento. In order to achieve this you need to develop a shipping method that can acquire rates based on quote items and your own rules (particular day and time)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your own custom shipping method. Take a look at this [blog](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method) and hopefully it will give you an idea on how you can develop a custom shipping method

Comment: is there no extension available for that? @msoro

Comment: I have not seen any magento extension that calculates shipping cost based on day and time. You will usually find extensions where shipping is calculated based on location, carrier, size or weight. So to be able to customize your shipping method you will need to develop your own shipping method.